# How to record audio in web application in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am doing a project.I want to record and save the audio input.I used mcisendstring but it is not working in a web application.please help.

Comment: ASP.NET runs on the *server* so it can't do anything that affects the client, like record audio. You can use HTML 5 and the getUserMedia API to capture an audio stream and then send it to the server

Answer (score -2):

You should use `flash` component for this.

I think [this](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/microphone.htm) will be helpful.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't really helpful, especially when the link doesn't address the actual question.